# Contemporary-set alternate history series where facial tattoos indicate type of magic

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I read this last year on my Kindle; there were 3 or 4 books in the series.

A girl was kicked out of her home when she was a teen after her brother died. Moved over her parents' garage. Had a brother she was banned from talking to.

Her best friend is Jo (who is a lesbian.)

The girl was studying 3 subjects in community college, one of which was leading to her being an EMT. Because of a will she must graduate with her masters by a certain age to receive access to/ownership of a house in New York and access to an old mage's secrets.

Because of a government program she is evaluated and is forced to get first one, then two, facial tattoos. She also teleports into the chamber of the Japanese Emperor.

After graduating and starting her mandatory government service she first starts at a "special" military boot camp and then is assigned to the State Department's China Desk.

While there she frees a dragon from the Chinese Emperor and cause a regime change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is  [*My Luck*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/54268669) by Mel Todd. It's part of a series of half a dozen books set in an urban fantasy alternate reality.

Per [review](https://authorgailmarie.com/tag/fantasy/):

> We meet our main character, Cori, in a small Georgia town, where she
> works as at a coffee shop. She isn’t magical, though 50% of the
> population is, but she does have a horrible knack for finding dead
> bodies. Her latest one, happens to have a piece of paper is his pocket
> with her name on it. Ostracized from her parents after the freak death
> of her brother, she’s in school to become an EMT. So soon, she can
> help save the people that keep dying around her. Cori Catastrophe.
>
> Working through her EMT education requires her to be internships at
> various hospitals but she also manages one with the local police
> department to help pay for school costs. Eventually, her best friend
> Jo emergences into an Arch Mage nd her family cuts ties for good,
> selling their house. Despite her family’s departure, she has been
> adopted by Jo’s family for the last 8 years. Her and Jo have an
> inseparable bond of friendship and plan to attend college together
> after the current semester.

Comment: BING!BING!BING! That's IT! THANK YOU!